# Move between sheets every 10 sec, and bring data every 20 min in one code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need a script that switches between sheets every 10 seconds, and then runs some code every 20 min that brings some data using copy-paste function, and then loop until I press "Esc".

This is my code so far:

```
Sub Move_Between_Sheets()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, t As Single, k As Long
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
i = 0
  j = Sheets.Count
  On Error GoTo exit_
  Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler

  Do
  For k = 1 To 3
    i = i + 1
    If i > j Then i = 1
    Sheets(i).Select
    t = Timer + 1
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
    If Timer < t Then Exit Do
  Next k
  Call BringPK03
  Loop
exit_:
End Sub 
------------------
Sub BringPK03()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim wbPlantillas As Workbook
Dim wbAplicativo As Workbook

Set wbAplicativo = ThisWorkbook
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'13. URL [Link]
'The database workbook is opened from WorkPoint. The sheets in database workbook are copied and pasted in wbAplicativo
   Set wbPlantillas = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jmartine\Desktop\Tracking Advance.xlsx", True, True)

   wbPlantillas.Sheets("FC Paso a Paso").Range("A1:AU4500").Copy

   wbAplicativo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AO1573").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

   wbPlantillas.Close savechanges:=False
   Windows("BringData.xlsm").Activate

   wbAplicativo.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Range("A1").Select
   Call Move_Between_Sheets


End Sub
```

My code runs until the function BringPK03 brings the data and paste it in my workbook, and then the code keeps going but somehow the move between sheets don't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your Move_Between_Sheets() you do select the sheet, but you don't activate it. The switching will only be done after activating it.